# WebStorm - Turn Power Save Mode off when laptop is charging

Tags: macos, webstorm

WebStorm on macOS has a Power Save Mode (more about what it does [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11725642/5811984)), which is useful to save battery for your laptop when you do not have an access to power.

[image: WebStorm > File > Power Save Mode]

However, when you are home and charging, you really want to turn Power Save Mode off to get those background inspections back. It does not turn off automatically when your laptop is charging. You have to do it manually every time.

**Is it possible to make WebStorm turn Power Save Mode off when laptop is charging?**

Searching 'power' (or similar) in WebStorm preferences, strangely enough, shows no results at all.
[image: Search 'power' in WebStorm settings has no results]

Comment: No such settings AFAIK. This ticket is quite opposite -- turn it on when not charging -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134314

Comment: Also check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119217 (sounds the same as above) .. but it has 1 comment that could be useful. Such suggestion appear in comment here and there (e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82693#comment=27-429407) but those 2 tickets are the best that I could find myself so far.