# How to let the JetBrains Rider show errors?

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider

[image]

Like this photo shows, there is no error showing up.

And also, the code analysis is enabled.
[image]

And if I run code inspect for those lines, the result is "no issues found".

Comment: I like your ABC 80 color theme! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the reason. There is a small button on the status bar. Click on it and we can configure its inspect settings. I dont know why Rider is not inspecting any error or warning in MainViewModel.cs or ViewModelBase.cs.

[image]

For those curious about why they have this Power Save Mode:

[What is "Power Save Mode" in IntelliJ IDEA and other Jetbrains IDEs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725605/what-is-power-save-mode-in-intellij-idea-and-other-jetbrains-ides)