# SonarLint plugin for IntelliJ IDEA suddenly stopped working - shows "No issues to display"

Tags: intellij-idea, static-analysis, intellij-plugin, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

[SonarLint plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint) for IntelliJ Idea suddenly stopped working.

Although it previously found a lot of issues, now there are no issues at all.
However there is no error message visible and everything seems in order.

[image]

No "well-known method" (restart IDEA, restart the computer, invalidate caches, re-configure the plugin, reinstall the plugin, re-create the project) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ accidentally switched into [Power Save Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11725605/2886891) (`File` | `Power Safe Mode`). As for why, I have no idea [*pun intended*], but I found other people complaining about some problems with IDEA when their laptop wakes up from sleep/hibernation(?) (This is just an unconfirmed rumour and I am not sure that it is this what caused the unwanted configuration change.)

[image]

I didn't find a fully exhaustive and comprehensive documentation on the JetBrains site, but in general, when this switch is active, IDEA doesn't perform a lot of various background activities to save power.

All what you need **to get the SonarLint plugin back to work** is to turn the Power Save Mode off again.

[image]

Based on this problem, the Sonar team created a ticket [SLI-1256](https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/SLI-1256) "Improve how we react to the Power Save Mode" to address it.